# How to return an object from two tables form a rails web serivce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models:
Event and Place.
Event has a property name place_id which points to Place.
Place has a column named place_name.

How do I write a web service that returns a json of events with each event also holds the associated place_name value.

I tried simply adding an attr_accessor field name place_name to the Event model and populate it manually after selecting the events.
But when I do:
render :json => events_collection_result

the place_name doesn't appear in the json.

Comment: `and populate it manually after selecting the events`..can you show how you tried..

Answer (score 0):

All of this logic falls under [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It's a very fundamental piece of Rails functionality, so it's very well documented. That guide should more than suffice.

You'll want to invoke `belongs_to :place` if your `Event` class definition. From there, you can access an Event's place name via `@event.place.place_name`, although I'd recommend you rename `place_name` to just `name`.

JSON won't display the association by default. There are plenty of ways to remedy this, the most basic of which is to overwrite `Event#to_json`, which is the method that is called by default when Rails attempts to produce a JSON representation of an ActiveRecord instance.

Comment: Thanks. I already know and use ActiveRecord Associations. My problem was with the JSON part. But I solved it already: I use attributes.merge to dynamically add attributes to the object before transforming it to json